# How to launch a project correctly?

Tags: python, jupyter

There is such a project https://github.com/WentianZhang-ML/FRT-PAD , I want to run it locally. At the very end it says that you can run as

```
python train_main.py \
--train_data [om/ci]
--test_data [ci/om]
--downstream [FE/FR/FA]
--graph_type [direct/dense]
```

I try to run this file in `jupyter`, but I get `SystemExit: 2`

Answer (score 0):

"--downstream [FE/FR/FA]" means you have to put FE or FR or FA after "--downstream"

Exeample:

```
python train_main.py \
--train_data om \
--test_data ci \
--downstream FR \
--graph_type direct
```

Or

```
python train_main.py --train_data om --test_data ci --downstream FR --graph_type direct
```

**For a Jupyter notebook you have to run like this:**

```
!python train_main.py --train_data om --test_data ci --downstream FR --graph_type direct
```

Comment: Also, this command needs to run in the terminal, not in a Jupyter notebook

Comment: Just need to add ! for Jupyter notebook. example `!python train_main.py --train_data om --test_data ci --downstream FR --graph_type direct`

Comment: Sure, but in a notebook environment, you may not have a `train_main.py`, so there isn't any reason to use the notebook to run an existing script. So, this assumes the notebook is started from the same folder as that file.

Comment: You can use `!cd /content/yourfolder && python train_main.py ...` to run the script.